# Team Foundation Server 2012 configuring email alerts

Tags: alert

Is there a way to add custom field in email alerts, I have custom (Non-core) fields and want that to be displayed in the email alerts that is generated by TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer is no: only Core Fields are available in Alerts.

The alternative is to setup a SOAP alert and use a tool like https://tfsalertsdsl.codeplex.com/ to collect additional data and send the email.